# How to make Jquery Datetime Picker to work on jquery v1.4.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I am using jquery v1.4.2 all over the site and this site is very huge. I have been developing this site for more than 2 years now. I wanted to use `jquery datetime picker` on one of my forms but it don't seems to work on `jquery v1.4.2`. So i included `jquery library v1.9.1` and i started to get so many errors on my site all over. Like `.live` is not a function as it is deprecated in the latest release of jquery. Than i tried jquery `.noConflict()` method after which i started to get more errors. I badly want to use it and i don't know how i can use it without changing my parent jquery library file. Any help in this matter will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at [jQuery migrate](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Jquery migrate

> This plugin can greatly simplify the process of moving older jQuery
>   code to version 1.9.0 or higher of jQuery by identifying deprecated
>   features. It can also restore those features so that older code can
>   run without needing any changes at all. We strongly recommend that you
>   use this plugin in your initial jQuery 1.9 upgrade — make it easy on
>   yourself, that’s why we wrote this plugin!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have replace my jquery file with the one you suggested and i have also included jquery migrate libray but now i am getting following error `TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`